# Undefined offset import csv

Tags: php, csv, undefined

i have a code that import csv in an array.
but when i run the code, it gives me undefined index.

Here the code

```
    $cid =mysql_select_db('prestashop',$connect);
define('CSV_PATH','IN/');
// path where your CSV file is located
$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "AnagraficaArticoliGruppi.csv"; // nome del file CSV
$csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
$theData = fgets($csvfile);
$i = 0;
while (!feof($csvfile)) {
    $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
    $csv_array = explode(";", $csv_data[$i]);
    $insert_csv = array();
    //definition array  origin csv
    22 $insert_csv['Ditta'] = $csv_array[0];
    23 $insert_csv['CodFamiglia'] = $csv_array[1];
    24 $insert_csv['CodSottoFamiglia'] = $csv_array[2];
    25 $insert_csv['CodGruppo'] = $csv_array[3];
    26 $insert_csv['Descrizione'] = $csv_array[4];
    27 $insert_csv['Stato'] = $csv_array[5];
    28 $insert_csv['NpDataModifica'] = $csv_array[6];
    29 $insert_csv['NpUtenteModifica'] = $csv_array[7];
    30 $insert_csv['NpDataTransfer'] = $csv_array[8];
    //modifica data-in-mysql-php/
    32 $datemod=str_replace('T', ' ', $csv_array[6]);
    33 $datetra=str_replace('T', ' ', $csv_array[8]);
```

and here the error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\TOECOMM\ps_category1.php on line 23.....
>   
> ...
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\TOECOMM\ps_category1.php on line 33

Can anybody explain me why?

Comment: Because array $csv_array not contains element with this offsets. Also you can use fgetcsv (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php) instead fgets+explode

Comment: thank you for the advice,
the strange thing is that if i echo one of these variables, it gives me a value

Comment: Have you blank lines in csv? Or its maybe last line (if it contains only "\n"). You can check count($csv_array) <= 1 and print line number to check it.

Comment: it not gives me blank values, this is the point